# TYPO3 realURL can't generate chinese URL

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have Chinese content in my TYPO3 where I need to generate URLs,
The content in Chinese and the generated URL is empty:
My Chinese language ID = 8.
Without RealURL I get my page displayed but with URL :

```
http://localhost/zh/locations-chinese/?tx_locations_locationsfe%5Blocation%5D=104&tx_locations_locationsfe%5BmyId%5D=104&tx_locations_locationsfe%5Baction%5D=list&tx_locations_locationsfe%5Bcontroller%5D=Location&cHash=b864e25ff5fba24b2e44ce0723265881
```

That's what I need to generate :

```
http://localhost/locations/berlin.html?L=8&cHash=32a89be23eb7dc2516893bdf0e1cc424
```

or

```
http://localhost/locations/柏林.html?L=8&cHash=32a89be23eb7dc2516893bdf0e1cc424
```

This is what I get :

```
http://localhost/locations.html?L=8&cHash=32a89be23eb7dc2516893bdf0e1cc424
```

with error :

> Page Not Found
>
> > Reason: Request parameters could not be validated (&cHash comparison
> >     failed)

That's my /typo3cong/realurl_conf.php

```
<?php
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['addRootLineFields'].= ',tx_realurl_pathsegment';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
    '_DEFAULT' => array(
        'init' => array(
            'enableCHashCache' => 1,
            //'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile',
            'enableUrlDecodeCache' => 1,
            'enableUrlEncodeCache' => 1,
            'postVarSet_failureMode' => '',
            'EnableAllUnicodeLetters' => true,
            'doNotRawUrlEncodeParameterNames' => true,

        ),
        'redirects' => array(),
        'preVars' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'nc' => 1,
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
        ),
        'pagePath' => array(
            'type' => 'user',
            'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
            'languageGetVar' => 'L',
            'languageExceptionUids' => '8',
            'expireDays' => 7,
            'rootpage_id' => 1,
            'firstHitPathCache' => 1,
        ),
        'fixedPostVars' => array(
            162 => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_locations_locationsfe[controller]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        //'action' => 'detail',
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_locations_locationsfe[action]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        //'detail' => 'list',
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_locations_locationsfe[location]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        //'action' => 'detail',
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',

                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_locations_locationsfe[myId]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_locations_domain_model_location',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'title',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                            'strtolower' => 1,
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                        ),
                        // language support (translated urls)
                        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                        'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                        'autoUpdate' => 1,
                        'expireDays' => 180,
                    ),

                ),
            ),
            163 => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_locations_locationsfe[controller]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        //'action' => 'detail',
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_locations_locationsfe[action]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        //'detail' => 'listprice',
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_locations_locationsfe[location]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        //'action' => 'detail',
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',

                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_locations_locationsfe[myId]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_locations_domain_model_location',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'title',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                            'strtolower' => 1,
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                        ),
                        // language support (translated urls)
                        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                        'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                        'autoUpdate' => 1,
                        'expireDays' => 180,
                    ),

                ),
            ),
        ),
        'postVarSets' => array(
            '_DEFAULT' => array (),
        ),
        // configure filenames for different pagetypes
        'fileName' => array(
            'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 1,
            'index' => array(
                'print.html' => array(
                    'keyValues' => array(
                        'type' => 98,
                    ),
                ),
                'sitemap.xml' => array(
                    'keyValues' => array(
                        'type' => 200,
                    ),
                ),
                'rss.xml' => array(
                    'keyValues' => array(
                        'type' => 100,
                    ),
                ),
                'rss091.xml' => array(
                    'keyValues' => array(
                        'type' => 101,
                    ),
                ),
                'rdf.xml' => array(
                    'keyValues' => array(
                        'type' => 102,
                    ),
                ),
                'atom.xml' => array(
                    'keyValues' => array(
                        'type' => 103,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you have a typo within your config.
It should read a lowercase `'enableAllUnicodeLetters' => true`

Unicode characters are url encoded automatically.

Answer (score 0):

A URL can only consist of ASCII characters and "cannot" include/understand Unicode characters, such as UTF-8.  You need encode (or substitute) any of the Unicode characters (Chinese), using what's called "percent encoding".

Comment: Any more detail please ? what should I change in my config file ?

Comment: I apologize as I am not fluent with PHP.  Typically, for this problem, I would create a function, which evaluates each character in the string/text and "percent encode" as necessary.  

In PHP this can be achieved using built-in functions, as follows:

urlencode(utf8_encode($string)); //for encoding
utf8_decode(urldecode($string)); //for decoding

Although not sure where "locations.html" is coming from (i.e. database data issue perhaps?).  If you expecting "berlin.html", but are receiving "locations.html", then that's not an Unicode issue, but rather data issue.